# Can't load class in HQL query creation

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-4

After upgrading glassfish to 4 version and hibernate to 4.3.5, I have strange problem with class loading.

So, I creating such HQL:

> SELECT new list(s.id, s.name, s.serviceGroup.id, s.serviceGroup.name, count(t.id), sum( COALESCE( t.dealerFeeActual, 0 ) + t.sum )) FROM GroupTransaction gt JOIN gt.transaction t JOIN t.service s  WHERE 1=1  AND ( t.date >= :date_1 AND t.date < :date_2 ) AND t.status in (:status_list) AND gt.node.id = :node GROUP BY s.id, s.name, s.serviceGroup, s.serviceGroup.name ORDER BY s.serviceGroup.id

and when I call em.createQuery, it throws exception:

> ! [2014-04-27T22:56:29.757+0600] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.system.util] [tid: _ThreadID=156 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1398617789757] [levelValue: 900] [[
>     ASURLClassLoader EarLibClassLoader : 
>   doneCalled = true
>   doneSnapshot = ASURLClassLoader.done() called ON EarLibClassLoader : 
>   urlSet = [URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/javaconfig-1.4.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/httpclient-4.1.2.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/async-http-client-1.7.0.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/collections-generic-4.01.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/httpcore-4.2-alpha2.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/jdom.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/smslib-v3.5.0.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/lib/jsmpp-2.1.0.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/lib/commons-net-2.2.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/jboss-archive-browsing.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/httpasyncclient-4.0-alpha3.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/cglib-2.2.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/poi-3.9.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/pduutils.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/httpcore-nio-4.2-alpha2.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/itextpdf-5.1.0.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/netty-3.2.7.Final.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/hibernate-ehcache-4.3.5.Final.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/commons-exec-1.1.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/httpclient-cache-4.1.2.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/kaptcha-2.3.2.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/json.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/jsmpp-2.1.0.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/javadbf-0.4.0.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/jdom-2.0.5.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/httpmime-4.1.2.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/backport-util-concurrent.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/commons-net-2.2.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/ash/projects/ermak2/dist/gfdeploy/ermak2/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar]
>
> doneCalled = false 
>   Parent -> org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@987c45
>
> AT Sun Apr 27 22:44:57 KGT 2014 
>   BY :[java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1588), com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.done(ASURLClassLoader.java:216), com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.preDestroy(ASURLClassLoader.java:184), org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarClassLoader.preDestroy(EarClassLoader.java:114), org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentContextImpl.getClassLoader(DeploymentContextImpl.java:260), org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentContextImpl.getClassLoader(DeploymentContextImpl.java:210), com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:482), com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219), org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491), com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527), com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523), java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method), javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356), com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522), com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546), com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423), com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108), com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762), com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674), com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534), com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224), org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297), com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246), org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191), org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168), org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189), org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119), org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288), org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206), org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136), org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114), org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77), org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838), org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113), org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115), org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55), org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135), org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564), org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544), java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)] Parent -> org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@987c45
>    **was requested to find class s.name after done was invoked from the following stack trace**
>   java.lang.Throwable
>           at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClassData(ASURLClassLoader.java:827)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:744)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:412)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:412)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:222)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:240)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getImportedClassName(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1287)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.QuerySplitter.getImportedClass(QuerySplitter.java:171)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.QuerySplitter.concreteQueries(QuerySplitter.java:111)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:111)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
>           at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.createQuery(EntityManagerWrapper.java:456)
>           at kg.ermak.transaction.TransactionReportBean.consolidatedReport(TransactionReportBean.java:158)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
>           at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
>           at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
>           at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
>           at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor183.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
>           at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
>          at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor184.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.**intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy644.consolidatedReport(Unknown Source)
>           at kg.ermak.transaction.__EJB31_Generated__TransactionReportBean__Intf____Bean**.consolidatedReport(Unknown Source)
>           at kg.ermak.reports.Consolidated.formReport(Consolidated.java:53)
>           at kg.ermak.reports.ReportServlet.request(ReportServlet.java:84)
>           at kg.ermak.servlets.ParentServlet.processRequest(ParentServlet.java:60)
>           at kg.ermak.servlets.ParentServlet.doPost(ParentServlet.java:212)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
>   ]]

Such exception throws several times itemize every field in message^

> was requested to find class **s.name** after done was invoked from the following stack trace

Another queries work, and Entity finding works, too.
The problem happens with one SessionBean only.

Comment: This happens to our server everytime we upgrade an application. However no problem occurs in the application, only the logs get flooded with thoses warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just needed to wait proper GF4 release for java 8.
This all works for now.